# how to show the dynamic data in hiChart using flutter?

Tags: flutter, highcharts

I want to show the response data using hi chart lib. There are multiple splines data coming from the API, so I am trying to show them in a list of models. But the graph is not showing in the chart.

Comment: I don't understand sorry. What's your problem exactly? Can you add some information?

Comment: Actually i am trying to show a graph using high chart library, by getting the chart data from an api.

Comment: Okay i understood, where is your problem exactly? What couldn't you do?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue with the sample on some online editor to share your code with the community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.